# how should I repair exFat data if I run ntfsfix on ubuntu?

Tags: data-recovery

I was runing ntfsfix on ubuntu for my "exFat" Data. Is there any method to repair my data back to correct format?

Thanks so Much!

Comment: Do you want to recover data from an ExFAT partition that you lost?

Comment: Both NTFS or exFAT can be corrected with Windows tools. There's no such tools for Linux.

Comment: @CelticWarrior i'll have to disagree, I've recovered data from lost NTFS, FAT and exFAT partitions in Ubuntu.

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh correct but he is correct too. There is no tool to -repair- exfat.

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh recovery has nothing to do with repair.

Comment: Tony, `ntfsfix` basically only changes one bit (the "dirty bit" of NTFS). It doesn't "repair" anything so it probably did not do much harm to the partition. You should at least be able to access it via TestDisk.

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh Yes I would like to recover data from an ExFAT, thanks

Comment: @CelticWarrior I also have windows PC, so what is the tools for doing that? thanks

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto I understand what is ntfsfix doing, but my friend plug on my Driver and run that operation. I will fry via TestDisk

Comment: As the answer says, testdisk can be used to retrieve data

Answer (score 6):

Why would you even attempt to use a tool for NTFS on a filesystem that is not NTFS?

[Exfatfsck](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man8/fsck.exfat.8.html) should be used to check exFat.  Mind though that this tool can only be used to perform a check. [Testdisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) can retrieve data from exFat but that also does not fix your filesystem.

But there is no native Linux tool to repair exFat. Use Windows to fix the problem.

Answer (score -1):

use testdisk.
create --> your disk --> choose table type --> Advanced --> choose your disk partition --> use arrow left and right to choose "Type" --> MSData --> exfat.

use arrow left and right to choose "Boot" --> use arrow left and right to choose BACKUP BS.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Bullet points would be better than arrows.